# JavaFX Desktop App with Hibernate - @Entity and other annotations are not recognized

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, javafx

So, I've decided to make a project with Hibernate and JavaFX.
I have designed the UI and tested it in a project I've created with Maven, using the archetype called "javafx-archetype-fxml" which works just fine.
Now I'm trying to add Hibernate to this project to manage the persistence layer.
I added the dependency in Maven, "hibernate-core" v.6.0.0 and proceeded to map the model classes with "@Entity" type annotations, but they aren't recognized by VSCode. Maybe I need to add a module to module-info.java?

@Entity Annotation not recognized.

[image: screenshot]

This is my pom.xml file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0.Beta1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.26</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>13</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>11</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.ignaciocassi.App</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is my module-info.java file:

```
module com.ignaciocassi {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires transitive javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires java.sql;
    opens controllers to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.ignaciocassi;
 }
```

I'm new to Maven and modular projects, and I want to learn. Any suggestions or help would be much appreciated.

Comment: All this information was really useful, although I still don't figure out how to check what module I have to add depending on the functionality I want to use. In this case, jakarta.persistence module added JPA annotations. I cant find any mentions on that on the Hibernate ORM guides. Anyway, your help was really useful, thanks @jewelsea .

Comment: Replaced comments with an answer.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having the same problem as me in the future, I recommend reading [Understanding Java 9 Modules - What they are and how to use them](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html) as suggested by @jewelsea.

What actually solved it for me, was adding the "requires jakarta.persistence" to Module-info.java, which provides JPA annotations.

Comment: The next thing you will need is to open the module to the hibernate module or make the module an open module as Hibernate needs to access internals of your entity classes to function properly.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is to get some of the additional info out of comments and into an answer and add some more contextual information.  It is supplemental to the [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69558507/1155209), which already notes:

> What actually solved it for me, was adding the "requires jakarta.persistence" to Module-info.java, which provides JPA annotations.

**Why requiring `jakarta.persistence` allows `@Entity` access**

The [`@Entity`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.0/apidocs/jakarta.persistence/jakarta/persistence/entity) annotation is for JPA, not hibernate (though hibernate can make use of it). Hibernate 6 depends on jakarta 3 to provide the `@Entity` definition, which it gets from the [`jakarta.persistence` package](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.0/apidocs/jakarta.persistence/jakarta/persistence/package-summary.html) in the [`jakarta.persistence` module](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.0/apidocs/jakarta.persistence/module-summary.html).

Adding `requires jakarta.persistence` clause to your `module-info.java` file allows access to the types exported by that module (which includes the `@Entity` type).

Note, if you make use of other JPA features like criteria, they can be in different packages, within the same module.  So, even if you use annotations from the [`jakarta.persistence.criteria`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.0/apidocs/jakarta.persistence/jakarta/persistence/criteria/package-summary.html) package, just requiring the `jakarta.persistence` module is sufficient because that module also includes the criteria package.

**What about the rest of Hibernate**

I can find little specific info on the web about what may be needed to be placed in module-info.java for using Hibernate 6.  The [current Hibernate 6 documentation](https://hibernate.org/orm/documentation/6.0/) did not mention it as far as I could tell (which I believe is a shortcoming in the documentation).

Note, that Hibernate is often used with other technologies, specifically [Spring Data JPA](https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-data-jpa).  If you are considering using Spring technologies in your application now or in the future (which I would advise over using a straight hibernate integration).  Spring will only really be well integrated with the JPMS module system when [Spring 6 and SpringBoot 3](https://www.infoq.com/news/2021/09/spring-6-spring-boot-3-overhaul/) are released.  So, although you may be able to get current Spring applications to work with JPMS, I would recommend instead deploying your application in a non-modular fashion (see the information below) and running some of the non-modular libraries such as any Spring libraries (and perhaps also the hibernate-core) off of the classpath.

**Understanding JPMS Modules**

To help understand modules: see [Understanding Java 9 Modules - What they are and how to use them](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html), which is a basic introduction to the Java Platform Module System (JPMS), from there you can do some independent research and study for more information if needed.

**Non-modular JavaFX applications**

Also note, that, you may be able to avoid these issues, but making your application non-modular (i.e. don't provide a `module-info.java` file in your application).  **The core JDK classes and JavaFX itself should be run off the module path**, but your application and other dependent libraries it used can either:

1. Your application can be modular and run off the module path

- by including a `module-info.java` file in your application.

2. Or, your application can be non-modular.

- by not including a `module-info.java` file.

For a non-modular application, your application classes and dependent libraries can be run off of the classpath rather than the module path.

For more information on this, see the [openjfx.io getting started guide](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#introduction), where it discusses modular and non-modular applications for common IDE setups and the creation of deployable run-time images.

The drawback of deploying a non-modular application is that you lose some of the benefits that modularity provides (such as stricter access controls).  But for some applications, this is an appropriate deployment target.

**Miscellaneous potential issues with your Maven setup**

I think the dependency type of `pom` is wrong. Probably there shouldn't be any type.  I think the `pom` type is only for importing a bill of materials in the [dependencyManagement section of the maven project file](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management).  A discussion of the usage of the `pom` type is in [the Baeldung spring maven bom tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-maven-bom).  I could be wrong, there may be other uses for the `pom` type, but the info provided is my current understanding.

You are using beta hibernate software, which is probably OK and might actually work better with JPMS modules, but be aware of that.

`hibernate-core` can still be found in the `org.hibernate`, but has moved for version 6 to `org.hibernate.orm`, so future releases might not be found under the old group.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Spring data JPA maven dependency, as @Entity annotation requires javax.persistence package.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.5</version>
</dependency>
```